# Borland C++ 5.02 how to set environment variable

Tags: c++, environment-variables

I know its an old compiler, I don't have any choice.  I want to set an environment variable from C, however the function setenv doesn't exist or at least I couldn't find it and putenv doesn't seem to work.

In my code I am calling:

```
    putenv("CPU=ELAN");
```

But it doesn't create and the environment variable.  I'm running the application from a DOS shell, if I create it manually using:

```
    SET CPU=ELAN
```

It works, I've searched around for a solution, but nothing, I've also tried:

```
    system("SET CPU=ELAN");
```

This doesn't work either.

Comment: maybe putenv is reporting some error? it should set errno. (BTW: system(...) could not work, as it is creating and executing external process)

Comment: - How do you check if the env variable is set?
- Is the setting done with the string literal as in your example, or is it actually some variable? (note that if it is variable, `putenv()` uses the value directly, so if it is altered or destroyed, the environment variable is directly affected as well)

Comment: When your program is launched, it inherits a copy of the parent process.  The putenv() function is working, but only within the environment of the program you wrote.  When the program exits, the environment it had is gone.  One clever way to handle this would be to have your program spit out "set CPU=ELAN" to a batch file.  After your program exits, then call that batch file.

Comment: Depending on what is your target platform, I suggest you use [SetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: @BradBales Right, that is indeed the case if you check the env variable after the program terminates. Setting the variable with `putenv()` is only valid during the program lifetime. You can check by `getenv()` inside the same program (after calling `putenv()`) to see if the variable has been set, but it will not be available after the program exits.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to modify the environment of the host session so the variable persists when the application terminates?